# Remove legend background for geom_point in combined ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-point

I want the legend to only show the black point for `Proporció sobre la despesa total`, without the purple background.

Here a sample of my dataset:

```
structure(list(decils_renda = structure(1:10, .Label = c("1r", 
"2n", "3r", "4t", "5è", "6è", "7è", "8è", "9è", "10è"), class = "factor"), 
    despesatotal = c(2681.8, 3543.7, 3960.3, 4356.8, 4767.3, 
    5229.9, 5057.8, 5799.5, 6096.8, 7228.4), despesamonetaria = c(2654, 
    3516, 3918.1, 4308.8, 4722.8, 5160.9, 5027, 5746.5, 6068.3, 
    7181.6), proporcio_despesatotal = c(18.6, 19, 18.4, 17.8, 
    17.1, 17.2, 16.6, 16, 15.2, 13.4), proporcio_despesamonetaria = c(26.7, 
    26.2, 24.2, 23.4, 21.9, 21.5, 20.9, 20.1, 19.2, 17.1), proporcio_despesatotal_ingressos = c(32.7, 
    26.1, 23.4, 20.1, 18.8, 17.8, 14.7, 15.2, 13.2, 10.4), proporcio_despesamonetaria_ingressos = c(32.3, 
    25.9, 23.2, 19.9, 18.6, 17.6, 14.6, 15.1, 13.1, 10.4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is the code I used for the graph:

```
plotalimentacio_2021_decils <- ggplot(alimentacio_2021_decils) +
  geom_col(aes(fct_inorder(decils_renda), despesamonetaria, color="despesamonetaria"), fill="#9A6584", width=0.5, alpha=1) +                
  geom_point(aes(fct_inorder(decils_renda), proporcio_despesamonetaria_ingressos*100, color="Proporció sobre els ingressos anuals"), size=3) +
  scale_color_manual(name="", labels=c("Despesa monetària", "Proporció sobre els ingressos anuals (eix dret)"), values=c("#9a6584","#000000")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", scientific = FALSE), breaks=seq(from=0, to=8000, by=1000),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .05)), 
                     sec.axis=sec_axis(~ ./100 ,  breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10), name = "% sobre el total d'ingressos")) +  
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color="black")+
  labs(
    title="Despesa en alimentació per decils de renda a Espanya (2021)",
    subtitle="En euros i proporció sobre els ingressos anuals",
    x = "Decils de renda", 
    y="",
    caption="Font: Elaboració pròpia a partir de dades de l'Enquesta de pressupostos familiars del 2021, base 2016, de l'INE.") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.justification = "left",
    legend.direction="horizontal",
    legend.margin=margin(t=-25),
    legend.text=element_text(size=12),
    legend.box.margin = margin(0,1,0.5,-1,"cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried +guides(fill = 'none')?

Comment: I get this error `Error in as.unit(e2) : object is not coercible to a unit`

Comment: I don't think I can help further without seeing the actual graph code/data itself. I don't think the purple background in the legend there can be removed with the theme() function, it would be elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Alternately, a potential fix here is to specify fill = 'purple' (or whatever color that is) *outside* of an aes() function, in your geom_bar()/geom_col() call directly, rather than fill = varname inside of an aes() function. This will also keep the fill color out of your legend.

Comment: I've just updated my code in the description.

Comment: I've tried what you said, but it isn't working either.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're trying to make a single legend work for both fill and color elements but without wanting to combine them. The solution is to have two separate legends, one for fill and one for color.

```r
ggplot(alimentacio_2021_decils) +
# Notice I've gotten rid of color for the geom_col
  geom_col(aes(fct_inorder(decils_renda), despesamonetaria, fill = 'despesamonetaria'), width=0.5, alpha=1)+                
  geom_point(aes(fct_inorder(decils_renda), proporcio_despesamonetaria_ingressos*100, color="Proporció sobre els ingressos anuals"), size=3)+
# I've added scale_fill_manual just referring to the bar
  scale_fill_manual(name = '', labels = "Despesa monetària", values = "#9a6584") +
# and scale_color_manual is edited to just refer to the point
  scale_color_manual(name="", labels="Proporció sobre els ingressos anuals (eix dret)", values="#000000") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", scientific = FALSE), breaks=seq(from=0, to=8000, by=1000),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .05)), 
                     sec.axis=sec_axis(~ ./100 ,  breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10), name = "% sobre el total d'ingressos")) +  
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color="black")+
  labs(
    title="Despesa en alimentació per decils de renda a Espanya (2021)",
    subtitle="En euros i proporció sobre els ingressos anuals",
    x = "Decils de renda", 
    y="",
    caption="Font: Elaboració pròpia a partir de dades de l'Enquesta de pressupostos familiars del 2021, base 2016, de l'INE.") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.justification = "left",
    legend.direction="horizontal",
    legend.margin=margin(t=-25),
    legend.text=element_text(size=12),
    legend.box.margin = margin(0,1,0.5,-1,"cm"))
```

The code example you gave causes the legend to overlap with the x-axis title, and I didn't change that, but you can see here the legend looks right

[image: Graph with two separate legends, one for fill and one for color]

Comment: I'm getting this error `Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 1 needed but only 0 provided.`

Comment: Hmm, odd, I don't get that error when running the code. Also, both manual scales have 1 value provided.

Answer (score 1):

One option to fix your issue would be to use the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend` to get rid of the `fill` for the "black" category using

```
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("#9a6584", NA)))
```

Additionally, in the code below I removed the outline around the legend key using `linetype="blank"` and finally removed the fill color for the legend key background via theme options.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(alimentacio_2021_decils) +
  geom_col(aes(fct_inorder(decils_renda), despesamonetaria, color = "despesamonetaria"),
    fill = "#9A6584", width = 0.5, alpha = 1
  ) +
  geom_point(aes(fct_inorder(decils_renda), proporcio_despesamonetaria_ingressos * 100,
    color = "Proporció sobre els ingressos anuals"
  ), size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "", labels = c("Despesa monetària", "Proporció sobre els ingressos anuals (eix dret)"),
    values = c("#9a6584", "#000000")
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::label_number(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","),
    breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 8000, by = 1000),
    expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .05)),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 100, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10), name = "% sobre el total d'ingressos")
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black") +
  labs(
    title = "Despesa en alimentació per decils de renda a Espanya (2021)",
    subtitle = "En euros i proporció sobre els ingressos anuals",
    x = "Decils de renda",
    y = "",
    caption = "Font: Elaboració pròpia a partir de dades de l'Enquesta de pressupostos familiars del 2021, base 2016, de l'INE."
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.justification = "left",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA),
    # legend.margin = margin(t = -25),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
    # legend.box.margin = margin(0, 1, 0.5, 0, "cm")
  ) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("#9a6584", NA), linetype = "blank")))
```

[image]